# Efficient way to compute an array matrix multiplication for a batch of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-einsum

I want to parallelize the following problem. Given an array `w` with shape `(dim1,)` and a matrix `A` with shape `(dim1, dim2)`, I want each row of `A` to be multiplied for the corresponding element of `w`.
That's quite trivial.

However, I want to do that for a bunch of arrays `w` and finally sum the result. So that, to avoid the for loop, I created the matrix `W` with shape `(n_samples, dim1)`, and I used the `np.einsum` function in the following way:

```
x = np.einsum('ji, ik -> jik', W, A))
r = x.sum(axis=0)
```

where the shape of `x` is `(n_samples, dim1, dim2)` and the final sum has shape `(dim1, dim2)`.

I noticed that `np.einsum` is quite slow for a large matrix `A`. Is there any more efficient way of solving this problem? I also wanted to try with `np.tensordot` but maybe this is not the case.

Thank you :-)

Comment: You could omit the ```j``` subscript in the output and there will be no need to sum the array as an extra step.

Comment: Tensordot is really just a generalization of einsum. If you want explicity, you should use einsum. Most optimizations are done under the hood anyways in numpy :)

Comment: `tensordot` reshapes and transposes its inputs, reducing the problem to a `np.dot`, with some further massaging after.  `np.einsum` is much more general.  `np.matmul/@` is **the** batched matrix multiplication function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [455]: W = np.arange(1,7).reshape(2,3); A = np.arange(1,13).reshape(3,4)
```

Your calculation:

```
In [463]: x = np.einsum('ji, ik -> jik', W, A)
     ...: r = x.sum(axis=0)
In [464]: r
Out[464]: 
array([[  5,  10,  15,  20],
       [ 35,  42,  49,  56],
       [ 81,  90,  99, 108]])
```

As noted in a comment, `einsum` can perform the sum on `j`:

```
In [465]: np.einsum('ji, ik -> ik', W, A)
Out[465]: 
array([[  5,  10,  15,  20],
       [ 35,  42,  49,  56],
       [ 81,  90,  99, 108]])
```

And since `j` only occurs in `A`, we can sum on `A` first:

```
In [466]: np.sum(W,axis=0)[:,None]*A
Out[466]: 
array([[  5,  10,  15,  20],
       [ 35,  42,  49,  56],
       [ 81,  90,  99, 108]])
```

This doesn't involve a sum-of-products, so isn't matrix multiplication.

Or doing the sum after multiplication:

```
In [475]: (W[:,:,None]*A).sum(axis=0)
Out[475]: 
array([[  5,  10,  15,  20],
       [ 35,  42,  49,  56],
       [ 81,  90,  99, 108]])
```